# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' WARNING: process exited with a(n) Unknown (1) error code

Tags: python

I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
WARNING: process exited with a(n) Unknown (1) error code
```

With my code looking like this:

```
import sys

a = int(sys.argv[1])
n = bin(int(sys.argv[2]))[2:]
m = int(sys.argv[3])


def real_multiply(x, y):
    if y == 1:
        return x * x
    else:
        return x * 2 * real_multiply(x, real_multiply(2, y - 1))


def mod(p, t, g):
    newa = p
    real_multiply(a, t)
    modus = newa - (g * (newa / g))
    print(newa, "mod", m, " = ", modus)


mod(a, n, m)
```

and I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting that. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because you are trying to substract a string object and an integer object, and that operation is not defined.

Comment: `n` (which becomes `t` and then `y` as it gets passed around) is a string.  Why did you apply `bin()` to it?  (And what was the point of calling `real_multiply()` inside `mod()`?  You didn't use the return value, and it has no side-effects).)

Answer (score 0):

It is only because of line no.3 it means that IndexError: list index out of range